# hosts file entry for domain pointing to shared hosting account

Tags: hosts

I have hosting account which is on shared hosting server.  My DNS is not able to resolve the server address.

What should be entry in etc/hosts so that it resolves the correct server address?

Few days back i was not able to access github.com, i resolved the issue by putting DNS entry on hosts file, but how do i do it for my own website because on same ip there might be 100s of domains pointing to it.

EDIT :

I am able to access my website, but some users using some specific internet service providers are not able to view.

Comment: Is this Linux?
Could you post the content of your /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: users are using windows, and they are not able to access mywebsite.

Comment: I think this is a good example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If a tiger is chewing your leg off, you don't take an aspirin to dull the pain. You deal with the tiger.   Your website isn't showing up in DNS for your clients, so fix that.

Comment: "users are using windows, and they are not able to access mywebsite" Your computer's hosts file won't solve that for them.

Comment: no its some specific users using some local internet service provider. I can access my website just like others, nut these are some specific users.

Answer (score 1):

You should talk to your system administrator about getting your dns servers fixed so you don't have issues with github and then you should contact your domain registrar with help for configuring your domain.

The issue resolving github seems to point to a bigger issue with whatever recursive dns provider you are using. Adding an entry to your hosts file is a hackey workaround that make break at anytime.

As for your hosting account... You need to configure the DNS with for your domain name to point tot he appropriate server ip. You registrar or shared hosting company can likely provide support for this.